# SharePoint Javascript Popup Link inside MasterPage

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, popup, master-pages

In SharePoint I am trying to create a link that pops up a window

```
<a id="Z5" href="javascript:popUp('<% $SPUrl:~site/Pages/Mine.aspx%>')" runat="server"  style="text-decoration:none;color:#000000">Mine</a>
```

But when I use that code i get a link with exactly javascript:popUp('<% $SPUrl:~site/Pages/Mine.aspx%>)' in my page how can I use the SPUrl and still have a javascript popup any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up switched my link to

```
<a id="Z5" href="javascript:popUp()" runat="server"  style="text-decoration:none;color:#000000">Mine</a>
```

Then changed my JS to

```
window.open("<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$SPUrl:~site/pages/Mine.aspx%>" />"
```

and it worked.